# Does disabling stock apps cause problems with phone on Android 6.0

Tags: applications, bluetooth, audio, 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth-audio

So I disabled all the stock apps and other apps I don't use or need in my phone and I am just curious if that could cause issues with the phone where audio eventually breaks.

I've been on support with verizon and after several resets I've ran my phone without any apps installed and the issue came back and the only thing I've done was use blue tooth with my car and disable stock apps.

I'm trying to convenience them that my Refurbished Droid Turbo 2 is a bad phone and while the issue seems like it would be software I can't explain what is triggering the issue software wise that even makes sense unless it was a bad firmware/software upgrade from 5?

The weird part is even if audio breaks, if you blue tooth up to the car it works just fine.

EDIT: 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the list of stock apps you disabled? The command `pm list packages -d` using [tag:adb] or with a terminal emulator could work.

Comment: Sure. Updated with disabled apps.

Answer (score -2):

There are many stock apps which you defenetely shoud'nt disable as it can problems to your stock frimware behaviour. I also once disabled lots of packages as i thought it will save battery and ram but it turns out there are extensions or side apps which are required by other apps to get/run their content. for example there is an sideapp called media storage which scans and stores media changes in your storage locations i.e. if you disable your music players like play music,phonograph,musixmatch,etc.. wont work and will show previous catched files insted of new files or currwent files. same way you may be facing same problem here. Just check which app does your audio player needs to run audio smoothly. re-enable it and restart your phone..this should solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer tries to address only the second half of the OP's question. Actually, they asked if disabling stock apps can potentially cause problems or not, as well. The lack of elaboration justifies my downvote.

Comment: well i explained how it caused problem in detail...duh bro!